# Pygame keys only running once

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
def walk():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    dist = 5
    frame = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                x = x - 5
```

This is part of some code to make my sprite move. But it tried to get it to print it while i was pressing the button for some reason it only print "yay" once until i press the key again. Someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to dedent the line `key = pygame.key.get_pressed():` and the two lines below. They are executed only once per event in the event queue because they are in the event loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`), but they should be executed in the `while` loop every frame.

```
def walk():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    dist = 5
    frame = 0
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            x = x - 5
```

Comment: Maybe we should create some canonical questions that deal with this and the other common questions that pop up nearly daily.