# Python; how can I make something move continuously

Tags: python, pygame

This is my Code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel =5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += vel

        win.fill((0,0,0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (x,y,width,height))
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I would like the rectangle move continuously when you hold down one of the buttons but it only moves once per press.
I'm just starting to learn Python and Pygame (as you may see) so I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame keys only running once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125916/pygame-keys-only-running-once)

Comment: `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and everything below should not be in the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here, is that you put the code to update the position in the event loop which means that your code ment to move the object is only run when pygame detects an event like a key press. But if you keep a key pressed down pygame does not register that as an event.

Simply remove all the code from `keys = pygame.key...` to `display.update()` from the for loop and put it in the while loop.

As such:

```
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (x,y,width,height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

The object that needs to move will now move continuously as long as the keys are held down!